# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, react-props

patientListContainerNew.js

```
...
        render: (text, rowData) => (
          <IconButton color="primary" aria-label="delete" size="small">
            <PatientEditContainer rowData={ rowData } />
            <Popconfirm Popconfirm 
             title="Are you sure？" okText="Yes" cancelText="No" 
             onConfirm={() => {handleDelete(rowData, "yes")}}>
              <DeleteForever fontSize="small" style={{ color: "#00ffff" }} />
            </Popconfirm>
          </IconButton>

...
```

patientEditContainer.js

```
...

const PatientEditContainer = ({ rowData }) => {

  const [editVisible, setEditVisible] = useState(false);

  const handleEdit = ({}) => {
     const { editPatient } = this.props;
     editPatient({ pid: rowData.pid, 
                   name: rowData.name, 
                   gender: rowData.gender, 
                   age: rowData.age, 
                   birth_date: rowData.birth_date });
   };

      return(
        <div>
        <EditIcon onClick={() => setEditVisible(true)} />
          <PatientInfoEdit
            visible={ editVisible } 
            setVisible={ setEditVisible } 
            onCancel={() => setEditVisible(false)}
            onEditPatient={ handleEdit }
            pid = {rowData.pid}
            name = {rowData.name}
            gender = {rowData.gender}
            age = {rowData.age}
            birth_date = {rowData.birth_date}
            key = {rowData.key}
          />
      </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({

});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
      editPatient: ({ pid, name, gender, age, birth_date, key }) => {
          dispatch(patientActions.editPatient({ pid, name, gender, age, birth_date, key }));
      }
  };
};

export default withRouter(
  connect(
  )(PatientEditContainer)
);
```

patientInfoEdit.js

```
const { Option } = Select;

const PatientInfoEdit = ({ visible, onCancel, onEditPatient, setVisible, pid, name, gender, age, birth_date, key }) =>{

    const [ data, setData ] = useState("reset");

    const [ birthDate, setBirthDate ] = useState(Moment());

    const layout = {
        labelCol: { span: 8 },
        wrapperCol: { span: 13 },
      };
    
    const dateFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD';

    const validateMessages = {
        required: 'This field is required!',
        types: {
          email: 'Not a validate email!',
          number: 'Not a validate number!',
        },
        number: {
          range: 'Must be between ${min} and ${max}',
        },
      };
    
    const dateConfig = {
        rules: [{ type: 'object', required: true, message: 'Please select birthdate!'}],
    };

    const onAgeChange = value => {
        const birth = Moment().subtract(value, 'years').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        setBirthDate(birth);
        
        console.log('onAgeChange : ' + birthDate);
    }

    const onFinish = values => {
        console.log('values ::::: ' + values);
        
    }

    const onOk = values => {
        const { patient } = values;
        const { pid, name, gender, age, birth, fundus, key } = patient;
        const birth_date = Moment(birth).format(dateFormat);
        onEditPatient({ pid, name, gender, age, birth_date, key });
    }   

    const [ form ] = Form.useForm();

    return (
        <Modal
            title="Edit Patient"
            centered
            visible={visible}
            onCancel={onCancel}
            okText='Submit'
            okButtonProps={{ type:'ghost', style:{ color:'aqua', 
                             borderColor:'aqua', borderRadius:'4px' }}}
            cancelButtonProps={{ type:'ghost', style:{ color: '#a9a9a9', 
                                 borderColor:'#a9a9a9', borderRadius:'4px' }}}
            onOk={() => {
                form
                    .validateFields()
                    .then(values => {
                        form.resetFields();
                        onOk(values);
                    })
            }}
            width={400}
        >
            <Form {...layout}
                name='patientInfo'
                validateMessages={ validateMessages }
                onFinish={ onFinish }
                autoComplete='off'
                form={form}
            >
                <Form.Item name={['patient', 'pid']} label="Patient ID" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
                    <Input placeholder={ pid }/>
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item name={['patient', 'name']} label="Name" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
                    <Input value={ birthDate } placeholder = { name }/>
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item name={['patient', 'gender']} label="Gender">
                    <Select
                        placeholder= { gender }
                        allowClear
                    >
                        <Option value="male">male</Option>
                        <Option value="female">female</Option>
                        <Option value="other">other</Option>
                    </Select>                    
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item name={['patient', 'age']} 
                           label="Age" rules={[{ type: 'number', min: 0, max: 99 }]}>
                    <InputNumber onChange={ onAgeChange } placeholder = { age }/>
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item name={['patient', 'birth']} label="Birth Date" {...dateConfig} >
                    <DatePicker format={ dateFormat } placeholder = { birth_date }/>
                </Form.Item>
            </Form>
        </Modal>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
 });

 const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
   return {
       editPatient: ({ pid, name, gender, age, birth_date, key }) => {
           dispatch(patientActions.editPatient({ pid, name, gender, age, birth_date, key }));
       }
   };
 };
 
 export default withRouter(
   connect(
       mapStateToProps,
       mapDispatchToProps
   )(PatientInfoEdit)
 );
```

error

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
handleEdit
D:/test/src/containers/patient/PatientEditContainer.js:23
  20 |  const [editVisible, setEditVisible] = useState(false);
  21 | 
  22 |  const handleEdit = ({}) => {
> 23 |     const { editPatient } = this.props;
     | ^  24 |     editPatient({ pid: rowData.pid, name: rowData.name, gender: rowData.gender, age: rowData.age, birth_date: rowData.birth_date });
  25 |   };
  26 | 
View compiled
onOk
D:/tese/src/pages/patient/PatientInfoEdit.js:69
  66 |        const { patient } = values;
  67 |        const { pid, name, gender, age, birth, fundus, key } = patient;
  68 |        const birth_date = Moment(birth).format(dateFormat);
> 69 |        onEditPatient({ pid, name, gender, age, birth_date, key });
     | ^  70 |    }   
  71 | 
  72 |    // const onGenderChange = value => {
View compiled
(anonymous function)
D:/test/src/pages/patient/PatientInfoEdit.js:94
  91 |         .validateFields()
  92 |         .then(values => {
  93 |             form.resetFields();
> 94 |             onOk(values);
     | ^  95 |         })
  96 | }}
  97 | width={400}
```

After the patientInfoEdit.js form appears, enter the information and click OK, an error occurs. I thought this code was perfect, but I got an error. I don't know why. I will post other parts of the code as well if you wish. Please tell me why the error occurred. I want to fix the props error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in `patientEditContainer.js` file

```
 const handleEdit = ({}) => {
     const { editPatient } = this.props; <- Here you are trying to fetch using `this`
     editPatient({ pid: rowData.pid, 
                   name: rowData.name, 
                   gender: rowData.gender, 
                   age: rowData.age, 
                   birth_date: rowData.birth_date });
   };
```

what you can do if you are passing props right:

```
const { editPatient } = props;
```

or

```
const PatientEditContainer = ({ rowData,editPatient }) => {...}
```

**Note**: Make sure you are passing correct props!